# Disable view code of function

Tags: javascript, function, return

Like this, if I made a function:

```
    function a() {
        alert("Hello!")
    }
```

I don't want you to be able to view the code like:

```
    eval(a)
```

Returns all the code but

```
    eval(a())
```

Returns the alert

When doing eval(a) I want it to not return the code, just nothing how?

Comment: You can't hide ECMAscript code, not like that, not anyhow. You can uglify and obfuscate code, which also easily can get reverted.

Comment: Yeah but it's for a calculator so it looks kinda crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always encapsulate your code in an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) so you don't leak variables to the global scope:

```
(function(){
  function a() {
    alert("Hello!")
  }
  // more stuff...
}());

console.log(eval(a)); //=> Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

You can also use a little trick to hide the function code with `bind`:

```
var a = function a() {
  alert("Hello!")
}.bind();

console.log(eval(a)); //=> function () { [native code] }
```

Whenever you think about using `eval`, think twice, there's probably a better way to do it.
If you just want to run the function, just do `a()`. No need for `eval` there.

Comment: As a tip, you probably shouldn't be using `eval`... avoid when possible. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Note that's kind of a hack, and it only works in modern browsers that support `bind`. My advice really is to think about another way without using `eval` if possible.

Comment: doesn't matter in my situation :)